# group child records by parentid and sum the amount linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a model with three properties

```
id int {get; set:}
name varchar {get; set:}
int fundedamount {get;set;}
list<child> childlist {get; set:}
```

and child like this

```
int id{get;set;}
int parentid{get;set;}
int amount{get;set;}
```

I want to group child records by parentid and sum the amount and assign it to parent.fundedamount using linq.

i am trying it like this:

```
 model.ForEach(f => f.childlist.Where(f1 => f1.parentid== f.Id).Sum(f2 => f2.Amount));
```

but how to assign it to parent.fundedamount? Do I need to use group by?

I have done without linq like this

```
               foreach (var f in model) {

                            foreach (var fi in f.childlist)
                            {
                                if (fi.parentid== f.Id)
                                {
                                    f.FundedAmount +=  (int)fi.Amount;
                                }
                            }  
                       }
```

http://prntscr.com/kgzgo4

please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I group by `childlist` by `parentId` to get a collection of distinct `id` associated with the sum `Amount`.

Next, for each group in this collection, I update `fundedamount` corresponding with the `GroupId`, means `Id` of the model.

```
model.childlist.GroupBy(x=> x.parentid).Select(group => new { 
               GroupId = group.Id,
               SumOfGroup = group.Sum(x => x.Amount)
           }).ToList()
             .ForEach(group => model.First(m => m.Id = group.GroupId).fundedamount = group.SumOfGroup )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make FundedAmount a read-only property, and have it return the sum of the Amount in the ChildList?

```
public int FundedAmount
{
    get { return ChildList?.Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0; }
}
```